# How can I pass the string value generated from "ex.Message" from my C# function to my Javascript function Sweet Alert, to display the error Message

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

ASP.NET Web Form Project. My C# function is using a try/catch for possible errors and if I get an error, I want to pass the string value of the error to my Javascript function that I'm calling inside of my `CreatRoleBtn_Click` function catch block.

C# Function:

```cs
protected void CreateRoleBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Roles.CreateRole(RoleNameTextBox.Text);
        RoleNameTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        RoleLabel.Text = "<h4>Role Created Successfuly!</h4>";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "create role", "createRoleSuccess()", true);
        GridView1.DataBind();

        DataSet dSet = r.GetAllRoles();
        AllRolesDropDownList.DataSource = dSet;
        AllRolesDropDownList.DataTextField = "RoleName";
        AllRolesDropDownList.DataValueField = "RoleName";
        AllRolesDropDownList.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        RoleLabel.Text = "<h4> " + ex.Message + " </h4>";
        string exMessage = ex.Message;
        string script = "window.onload = function() { createRoleFailure('" + exMessage + "'); }; ";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "fail to create role", script, true);
    }
}
```

Javascript Function using Sweet Alert for Fail:

```js
function createRoleFailure(exMessage) {
    console.log('testing');
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Failed!',
        text: exMessage,
        timer: 3000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        didOpen: () => {
            timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                const content = Swal.getHtmlContainer()
                if (content) {
                    const b = content.querySelector('b')
                    if (b) {
                        b.textContent = Swal.getTimerLeft()
                    }
                }
            }, 100)
        },
        willClose: () => {
            clearInterval(timerInterval)
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.timer) {
            console.log('I was closed by the timer')
        }
    })
}
```

Javascript Function using Sweet Alert for Success:

```js
function createRoleSuccess() {
    console.log('testing');
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Successful!',
        text: 'New Role was created!',
        timer: 3000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        didOpen: () => {
            timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                const content = Swal.getHtmlContainer()
                if (content) {
                    const b = content.querySelector('b')
                    if (b) {
                        b.textContent = Swal.getTimerLeft()
                    }
                }
            }, 100)
        },
        willClose: () => {
            clearInterval(timerInterval)
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.timer) {
            console.log('I was closed by the timer')
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: The Sweet Alert function did not fire and display the message pop-up box. Then when I successfully create a new role, the Sweet Alert pop-up worked properly and fires, but not when I tried making the function fail by recreating the same exact role.

Answer (score 0):

Since the success flow works, it should be

```cs
     try
     {
          .....
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          RoleLabel.Text = "<h4> " + ex.Message + " </h4>";
          string exMessage = ex.Message
                             .Replace("'", "\\'")
                             .Replace("\"", "\\\"")
                             .Replace(@"\", @"\\");
          string script = "createRoleFailure('" + exMessage + "')";
          ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "fail to create role", script, true);
     }
```

Comment: That didn't work as well. I also was getting the following error from the code I've posted: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. But I don't see where I'm missing a )

Comment: Could you provide your current approach? And what is value of exMessage?

Comment: @brissonl I don't know what is value of exMessage. But I have added some logic for escape character. You could try again.

Comment: the ex.Message is the argument exception message if I were to get an error/argument while running the function. I made some progress with my issue. I turned the ex.Message into a JSON object and passed it to my javascript. Now I'm trying to figure out how to turn the JSON object into a string I can use to replace my text: filed in my Javascript createRoleFailure() function. I think I need to use a controller. Any ideas? (I have successfully sent the object to javascript so far & have it displaying in my console.log)

Comment: protected void CreateRoleBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string message;
            jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ErrorMessage());
            try
            { I passed a test json object with 2 paramters to my Javascript

Comment: Trying to figure out how to now turn the var json into a string so I can use it to replace my "text:" field  ->   function createRoleFailure(exMessage) {     

            var json = JSON.parse('<%=jsonString%>');
            var string = JSON.stringify(json);
            console.log(json.name2);
            console.log(string.name2);
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Failed!',
                text: string.name2,

Comment: Have you try the answer? I have updated it again.

Comment: yes, I tried that method as well & it didn't work still

Comment: Could you provide the complete value of ex.Message?